# Git - How to commit a local repository to a subfolder of another local repository?

Tags: django, git, openshift

I have a Django project that I've started some time ago and I was hosting it at bitbucket. Now I need to host it at openshift, and the way to do that is that they provide you with a git repository and every time you push they deploy automatically. The problem is that the repository comes with several top-level folder for configuration and setup, and the effective django project must be inside a subfolder called wsig/openshift.

My question is, how can I commit my changes from my local django repository to the wsig/openshift subfolder of my local openshift repository? Because I intend to continue to develop on the bitbucket/local repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). From the docs:

> Submodules allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a
> dedicated subdirectory of the source tree, always pointed at a
> particular commit.

So you would do and would have the bitbucket repository as a seperate repository embedded in a subfolder of the openshift repository by running

```
git submodule add path_to_bitbucket folder/in/openshift
```

in the openshift repository.

You will have to run an occaisonal `git submodule update` to keep openshift up to date but you probably already expected extra work of that sort.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I looked more into submodules and several places recomended using subtrees instead, one useful link I found was http://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges

Comment: @ibrabeicker Subtrees would work too the difference basically boils down to that whith subtrees you have to watch what you are commiting and with submodules you have to remember to update before pushing. I went with submodules because you sounded like you wanted to have the repositories in different folders and only wanted to push to openshift to deploy. If you want to work in the openshift repositories subfolder instead subtree would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem too! Is highly annoying but **I took another road**:

Why don't you create a Python 2.7 project from scratch? Current Django structure is honestly annoying. The way I did was:

1. Create an openshift project which was in that annoying structure.
2. Copy, preserve (in my local FS, not in Openshift) a copy of settings.py and wsgi.py.
3. Discard that project, and start a bare Python 2.7 project.
4. Check it out to my local FS, create a Django project **in my local fs**.
5. Replace the contents of wsgi and settings **accordingly** (adapting any possible misplaced paths - it's easier than it looks).
6. Commit/push (this new structure).

You will do differently in point 4: you will checkout that remote branch (bitbucket) as well, merge it on the openshift branch, change accordingly those files in point 5, and push the openshift branch.

There you have a brand-new project, matching your structure (perhaps you want to configure both remote branches in your environment: openshift and bitbucket).

That's the way I did and honestly I have nothing to regret.

**Offtopic, but perhaps would be useful since you're using Django**: This is specially important if you want to -also- use (gunicorn|uwsgi)+nginx (with a custom cart. which does not provide apache but nginx, and python), and so cannot use the default Django cart.